# Rudin's RCA Theorem $2.20$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

There are the definitions which we need for the proof of the theorem:
[image]

[image]

There is the theorem:

[image]

There is the proof:

If $f$ is any complex function on $R^k$, with compact support, define

$\Lambda_n$$f$ $=$ $2^{-nk}$$\sum_{x\in p_n}$$f(x)$ $(n = 1,2,3,....)$,

where $P_n$  is as in  $2.19$.

Now suppose $f$ $\in$ $C_c(R^k)$, f is real, $W$ is an open $k$-cell which contains the support of $f$, and $\epsilon$ $\gt$ $0$. The uniform continuity of $f$ shows that there is an integer $N$ and that there are functions $g$ and $h$ with support in $W$, such that

$(1)$ $g$ and $h$ are constant on each box belonging to $\Omega_N$,

$(2)$ $g$ $\leq$ $f$ $\leq$ $h$

$(3)$ $h$ $-$ $g$ $\lt$ $\epsilon$.

If $n$ $\gt$ $N$ , Property $2.19(c)$ shows that

$\Lambda_N$$g$ $=$ $\Lambda_n$$g$ $\leq$ $\Lambda_n$$g$ $\leq$ $\Lambda_n$$h$ $=$ $\Lambda_N$$h$.

Thus the upper and lower limits of {$\Lambda_n f $} differ by at most $\epsilon$ $vol(W)$, and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have proved the existence of

$\Lambda f $ $=$ $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\Lambda_n f$ ($f$ $\in$ $C_c(R^k)$)

I don't understand how do we get the first condition from the uniform continuity of $f$:

$g$ and $h$ are constant on each box belonging to $\Omega_N$

I also don't understand How do we get that $\Lambda_N g $ $=$ $\Lambda_n g$, if $n$ $\gt$ $N$ by the property $2.19(c)$.

And the last question : Why do the upper and lower limits of {$\Lambda_n f$} differ by at most $\epsilon$ $vol(W)$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because f is uniformly continous there is a $\delta > 0$ s.t. for all $x,y$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$ we get $d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$. Now we choose $N$ big enough, such that each boxing of $\Omega_N$ has diameter less than $\delta$.
Now we can choose g to be the minimum of f and h to be the maximum of f on each box of $\Omega_N$. By uniform continuity the distance of f and g on each box of $\Omega_N$ is $\epsilon$.

If we now take $n > N$ the boxes of $\Omega_n$ all lie in a box of $\Omega_N$ on these $g,h$ are constant so the value of $\Lambda_N g = \Lambda_n g$ doesn't change. Maybe write it down for an interval or the plane.

As g and h differ by at most $\epsilon$ and have to be zero outside W, the function $h-g<\epsilon$ on W, and as the measure of the constant function $1$ is the volume, the measure of the constant function $\epsilon$ is $\epsilon*vol(W)$